# How can I assign the output of a function with parameters to a variable using bash?

Tags: linux, bash

```
example (){
......
local var
......
return $var 
}

user_val=$(example $number1 $number2)
```

I need user_val and i will it. I got error. Code can't detect the function when I try it this way.

Comment: `user_val= example $number1 $number2` I tried it but can not assign

Comment: `$()` captures the output of the command, not the return value. Change `return` to `echo`.

Comment: Replace last line with `example "$number1" "$number2"; user_val="$?"; echo "$user_val"`

Comment: @Cyrus Note that that will only work for a numeric value between 0 and 255.

Comment: Even then, the purpose of a function's return value is not to provide data to the caller, but to provide an exit status indicating whether the function succeeded or failed. "Function" is an extreme misnomer for this particular shell construct.

Answer (score 2):

@Barmar is correct. Replace `return` with `echo` in your function. Using `var=$(...)` assigns the *output* of the function to the variable.

When using `return` the value is saved in `$?`.

Comment: Note that the return-code special variable `$?` is a an 8-bit integer (byte).

Comment: an _unsigned_ 8-bit int (char)